# Error reporting is "disabled by Group Policy" but the relevant Group Policy seems to be not configured

Tags: windows-8, group-policy, soluto

The Windows Action Center nagged me to send custom error reports. However, it can't do so because "Never check for solutions" is checked and "Some settings are controlled by Group Policy."

[image: enter link description here]

Digging into the Group Policy finally got me to *Local Computer Policy → Administrative Templates → Windows Components → Windows Error Reporting*. Lo and behold, all settings are on "Not configured."

[image: enter link description here]

The description for "Disable Windows Error Reporting" says that forcing it to Disabled (yay double negatives) isn't enough, for *Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System → Internet Communication Management → Internet Communication settings* takes precedence over it. All the settings there, however, are also Not Configured.

Why is this? What's the problem here? Is this perhaps Soluto's own custom (and rather useless, I must say) error reporting tool at work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting was locked by Soluto's custom error handler. Right click on the Soluto icon in the notification area, pick Advanced and then disable "Handle Application Crashes." This unlocks the setting.

For completeness sake I'll mention the setting to reenable Windows Error Reporting is found inside the Action Center itself: *(in the sidebar) Change Action Center Settings → (scroll down) Related Settings → Problem reporting settings.*

Comment: Its pretty bad when the answer is more confusing then the question itself.

Comment: @Ramhound How is the answer confusing?